# Weird Sequences

Tags: number-sequence

Found this weird sequence: $$8110423, 259974, 9814143, 5512166, 113322, ?$$

The possible answers are:

a) $334455$, b) $7911132$, c) $9841233$, d) $872236$.

The correct answer is b), but I can't figure out why, and no explanation was given. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

> The sum of first two digits and the last two digits as a two digit addition gives the rest of the number (middle).

Comment: I see.  It is not a sequence, it is a common property you were looking for.