# Computer Puzzle - Arithmetic Of The Day

Tags: riddle, word, story, no-computers, language

Harou, a Japanese teacher in the school, noticed a ship made of paper outside her office.
When she unfolds the paper, she saw something strange.
There is something that looks like a riddle, followed by some weird arithmetic lines.

---

Riddle:

> My prefix is something that controls you.
> My suffix is something that students mustn't do.
> My infix is  one over nothing.
> My whole is the key to the lines below.

Code:

> (1) $82+1.13-1.1-1.1>32+1.1<19+1.15-1.1+1.11+1.15-1.1>1.1<14+1.3-1.4-1.3-1.11+1.$
> (2) $70+1.6+1.11-1.6+1.1>32+1.1<14+1.2-1.14-1.1-1.1>1.1<5+1.5+1.1>1.1<5+1.14-1.8+1.12-1.15+1.8-1.7+1.3+1.13-1.$
> (3) $70+1.9+1.6+1.3-1.1>32+1.1<15-1.2>79+1.2<9+1.2>1.2<6+1.1>1.1<1+1.2-1.4+1.20-1.17+1.13-1.$
> (4) $70+1.6+1.3-1.7+1.1>32+1.1<4+1.5-1.1+1.1>1.1<1-1.9-1.1>1.1>49+1.$
> (5) $83+1.16-1.12+1.5+1.8-1.11-1.13+1.10-1.$
> (6) $65+1.1>32+1.1<17+1.3-1.6+1.7-1.10-1.1>1.1<12+1.11-1.2+1.1>1.1<2+1.5+1.1>1.33+1.33-1.1<5+1.2-1.3+1+1.20-1.17+1.13-1.1>1.1<3+1.7+1.3-1.7-1.$

---

Question: Find the hidden six-letter word.

> This may be hard.

Hint 1:

> Why did the student fold the paper into a ship?

Hint 2:

> The $<$ and $>$ are not self-defined operators.

Hint 3:

> The riddle reveals a programming language.

Hint 4:

> You can use this one to raise things:
>  $1,10-1[22-1.1,10-1]$

Hint 5:

> All the numbers matter.

Hint 6:

> $70+1.3+1.13+1.17-1.1>32+1.1<2-1.15+1.3-1.4+2.14-1.14+1.$ makes 0.

Hint 7:

> Notice that the [arithmetic](/questions/tagged/arithmetic) tag is missing.

Comment: Previous question: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100199/sequence-puzzle-first-question-of-42

Comment: Can we have a hint for the last part, please? It's been a few months.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer (to Riley Riddle)

*warning: spoilers contain profanity*

> Brainfuck

My prefix is something that controls you

> **brain**: Your brain controls your actions

My suffix is something that students mustn't do

> **f*ck**: Students (especially high-school/lower-school ones) should not f*ck (have sex)

My infix is one over nothing

> **inf**: this is a shorted version of infinity, or the result of dividing 1 by 0

And it's a programming language, as noted by a hint

I have no idea how to go fro here.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer** (almost done; can't figure out the last part)

*Warning: The design of this puzzle pretty much requires some mild profanity, so consider yourself warned.*

## Riddle

*Note: I'd already figured this part out before [@bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble) posted her answer.*

Looking at the code, I recognized it as

> based on the programming language called "Brainfuck."

Looking at the riddle,

> My prefix is something that controls you.

> The prefix is "brain," which is also the name of what controls us.

> My suffix is something that students mustn't do.

> The suffix is "fuck," which, of course, students shouldn't do.

> My infix is one over nothing.

> The infix is "inf." $\frac{1}{0}$ (one over nothing) is sometimes said to represent infinity, which is often abbreviated "inf." More formally, $$\lim_{n\to 0^+}{\frac{1}{n}}\to\infty$$

> My whole is the key to the lines below.

> The whole, "Brainfuck," is the name of the programming language for the code.

## Code

> Brainfuck only has the following characters: `><+-.,[]`. You can read more about these commands on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Commands). To summarize them, `>` and `<` move the data pointer one cell right or left, respectively. `+` and `-` respectively increment and decrement the data at the pointer. It does not have numbers, so I had to figure out what the numbers were for.

## Numbers‽

> My first guess was that a number meant to add that number. That was wrong. My next guess was that a *digit* meant to add that number. Also wrong. Then, I noticed that it alternated between numbers and commands, so I decided that the numbers probably meant to run the following command that many times. This turned out to make sense.

### Decoding

> I tried using Hint 6 as a "practice run" to see if I was right. I noticed that each `.` was preceded by a `1` most of the time, with the `2.` corresponding to what I hoped was merely a double letter. This gave me more confidence. Using the value at the pointer for each output command as the ASCII value for a character, Hint 6 says "FIVE CROSSES" makes 0. At this point I didn't know what that meant, but I knew "FIVE CROSSES" was definitely not gibberish. (I'll explain this later at the point in the process that I figured it out.)

> Using the principles I used to decode Hint 6, the 6 ASCII-encoded messages are:
>  (1) 82 69 68 32 87 72 73 84 69 32 83 80 76 73 84
>  (2) 70 76 65 71 32 85 83 69 68 32 73 78 32 83 69 77 65 80 72 79 82 69
>  (3) 70 79 85 82 32 67 79 76 79 82 32 83 81 85 65 82 69
>  (4) 70 76 73 80 32 84 79 80 32 79 70 32 49
>  (5) 83 67 79 84 76 65 78 68
>  (6) 65 32 82 79 85 78 68 32 80 69 71 32 73 78 32 65 32 83 81 85 65 82 69 32 72 79 76 69

> Converting these numbers to text, the messages/clues read:
>
> ```
> (1) RED WHITE SPLIT
> (2) FLAG USED IN SEMAPHORE
> (3) FOUR COLOR SQUARE
> (4) FLIP TOP OF 1
> (5) SCOTLAND
> (6) A ROUND PEG IN A SQUARE HOLE
> ```

> These clues each correspond to a signal flag as follows:
>  (1) ? (RED WHITE SPLIT)
>  (2) O (FLAG USED IN SEMAPHORE)
>  (3) ? (FOUR COLOR SQUARE)
>  (4) ? (FLIP TOP OF 1)
>  (5) M (SCOTLAND)
>  (6) ? (A ROUND PEG IN A SQUARE HOLE)
>  To figure out which system to use for the numeral 1, I noticed that five crosses makes 0 in the U.S. Navy only. (This is when I finally understood Hint 6.)

This is the farthest I got. I've gotten past all the hints, but I'm stuck.