# This puzzle's value is 334

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, word-property, formation-of-numbers, word-sequence

The **28th of october** is valued by 40. **This sentence is valued by** 17. This paragraph is valued by 143.

This puzzle is valued by 334.

Can you give the value of **Puzzling StackExchange**?

Comment: Does the value of the puzzle include its tags?

Comment: @bobble :) Puzzle's name doesn't count too (would be very strange otherwise!). Puzzle exactly starts at "The 28th..." and finishes at "StackExchange?" :)

Comment: Relevant interesting question (disclaimer: yes it's my own; that's how I know about it) -- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101357/grading-quizzes-except-words-this-time

Comment: Isn’t this paragraph and this puzzle the same?

Comment: @Jingbothedude, I meant the first three sentences for the paragraph and the three lines for this puzzle :)

Comment: Is the ? at the end meant to be in bold and I take it that it is correct that 28 is bold but 17 is not bold, although it would seem to me that 17 is part of the second sentence (oh and +1 for interesting puzzle)

Comment: ? is not bold. 28 is clearly bold while you may arrive at a sort of infinite loop if 17 would also be. That's why it is choosen and meant to not bold it :) BTW: this comment is kind of hint :) Maybe I'll use it for the next hint if no answer is provided until then!

Comment: What if the answer is simply "no"

Comment: @Nilster, what are you waiting before writing your answer? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give the value of **Puzzling StackExchange**?

> No, I can't! ~ (;

Reasoning:

> After viewing this problem, I noticed a loophole in the question. Instead of 'What is the value,' it asks '**Can** I give the value.' In response to my too-brief answer, @JKHA confirmed that my answer was correct, but said that I needed to back up my answer.

> There are 5 values that correspond to phrases in the puzzle. They appear to have a vague direct correlation to the length of each phrase, but I concluded that, without a convoluted function or cypher, there wasn't enough information to answer the question with any certainty. The tags didn't help either, ranging from  [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) to [word-sequence](/questions/tagged/word-sequence).

> Thus, I concluded that the correct answer must take advantage of the grammatical loophole. And to quote English teachers everywhere:
> "I don't know, *can* you use the restroom?"

Comment: Rot13(V guvax lbh fubhyq erzbir gur "Fbzrbar ryfr zvtug or noyr gb, ohg abg zr!" cneg :D
Gur qvssvphygl oruvaq zl chmmyr jnf gb obgu svaq inyhrf abg gbb boivbhf fb fbzrbar jbhyq vzzrqvngryl svaq n (pbvapvqrapr) nafjre naq abg gb pbzcyvpngrq fb crbcyr jbhyq qverpgyl fnl, gurfr inyhrf ner gbgny abafrafr)  :)

Comment: @Rewan Demontay - I realize that my answer is unintended, but it isn't wrong! If the question had been worded 'What is the value of Puzzling StackExchange,' I would've withheld. Also, I did leave a comment, to which the author replied. I took this as an invitation to submit this particular answer. Best regards - Nilster :)

Comment: @Nilster, your answer is correct, specially with regards to the comment I made using Rot13. However, I think you need to explain a little more why your answer is the one, maybe using my comment to your answer :)

Comment: I think the problem here is that your initial answer came across as a joke rather than a serious attempt to answer the question. It appears that *by accident* your joke is actually the correct answer to a trick question; however, without being able to explain exactly *why*, it still isn't a *good* answer to this question. How do the scores given correlate to the words they represent? What is it about 'Puzzling Stack Exchange' that makes it impossible to calculate a score for it? Unless you can provide something solid to explain those aspects of the puzzle, this may well end up deleted, sorry!

Comment: @Nilster Ah, my bad! Similar to what Stiv said, it looked like some bad comment as an answer in the review.

Comment: (Unfortunately, I am unable to revoke my 'Delete' vote, placed before the edit was made... I hope you can come up with a rationalised answer to the question to avoid the deletion going through! This is also a lesson to me to avoid placing a hasty Delete vote when the user is actually still actively engaging with the OP and the puzzle... We live and learn. Good luck!)