# Are we scoring numbers now?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

So from [a couple](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101240/scoring-a-grid) [other puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101357/grading-quizzes-except-words-this-time), you might remember that I'm a professor of *A*wesomeness at the Ad H*oc* University! This time, I've given my students some numbers and *t*heir scorez. They need to te*ll* me how I scored them!

Here we are:

> 197 = 26 + 592 = 618
>
> 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
>
> 1337 = 44 + 8584 = 8628
>
> 43770 = 163 + 83104 = 83267
>
> 7 = 16 + 52 = 68
>
> 2020 = 63 + 2752 = 2815

Hint 1:

> You remember how I said "Note: all the information of the puzzle is in the blockquote; nothing outside the blockquote is relevant!" in my [Scoring a grid puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101240/scoring-a-grid)? Yeah, well I didn't say that here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off

> The 'strange' letters in the introduction are:
>  `A oc t z ll`
>  These are either written in italics or in `z`'s case slang in 'scorez'
>  `aoctzll` is an anagram for `collatz` (and also `lolcatz`)

This of course hints towards

> The [collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), a famous unsolved problem in mathematics. Simply put, do the following to a positive integer until it's equal to 1
>  - If it's even, divide by 2
>  - If it's odd, multiply by 3 and add 1

Now let's note:

> If we take the leftmost number $n$ of each line, apply the collatz procedure to it, count the number of steps $s$ it takes to reach 1: The next number in the line is always equal to $s$.
>  And the next, third, number is the highest value the procedure reaches in between. Adding those two together is the final score.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why this was downvoted. Nice spot Lukas +1

Comment: Great job! You just beat out David G.

Comment: Also, nice find with the `lolcatz` thing. That's hilarious.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the answer by @Lukas Rotter:

> I had notice A oc t ll
>   but I missed the z.
>   I think my brain just elides spelling errors in public forums.

> And @Lukas Rotter is correct, it is based on the Collatz conjecture.

I looked at it more deeply, and found, that in A = B + C = D

> A is the starting number.
>   B is the number of iterations to reach 1.
>   C is the highest number reached.
>   D is B + C

Thus, for example, we would see:

> 3 = 7 + 16 = 23

> Because the sequence is:
>   3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
>   7 steps, max of 16

Comment: Nice job! Unfortunately, Lukas edited his answer 2 minutes before you posted yours, so he is correct.

Comment: I hate it when it takes too long to write my answer.

Answer (score -3):

I am going to give it a try, hoping that my answers are correct..

$197=9+9+7+1=26$
$97*(7-1)+9+1=592$
$26+592=618$

$1=1*0=0$
$1^1=1$
$0+1=1$

$1337= (7^2+1)-(3+3)=44$
$(7-1)*1337+337+133+(33*3-7)=8584$
$44+8584=8628$

$43770=(7*7*3)+(7+7+3)-3^0=163$
$3*377*70+(4377-437)-(7+3-4)=83104$
$163+83104=83267$

$2020=20+20+20+2^0+(2+0)=63$
$(20*20*7)-(20+20+7+2^0)=2752$
$63+2752=2815$

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the answer to the puzzle? I'm not sure I see any logic here - it looks like randomly arranging digits and operations, with no particular pattern.

Comment: Very interesting try! (+1) It's rather convoluted, though, and not correct.

Comment: The logic is using the digits of the numbers in the first column  of the question to formulate the numbers  beside them.. In my opinion there is no pattern in the numbers given in the question.

Comment: @Voldemort's Wrath. By putting 1, I mean (+1).

Comment: What do you mean by comment #2? And if you don't see a pattern, then _you're_ mistaken, not the question.

Comment: If you think there is a pattern that is OK with me